How to enable MFA for Office 365 users without using Conditional Policies or manually enabling per-user MFA
I'm trying to enable Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) for Office 365 users, but I want to avoid the following methods:

Using Conditional Access Policies in Azure Active Directory.
Manually enabling MFA on a per-user basis.

Both our account and our customer's account have security defaults enabled, and the customer is successfully using MFA without the above options. We would like to implement a similar solution on our account.
Is there a way to enforce MFA for users under these conditions?
